# Porting SDL3 game to android

Tags: android, gradle, apk, porting

I've been trying to port my SDL3 game to android, the application builds, but upon opening the application it crashes immediately, I looked into logcat and it prints this error:
**Error**

```
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:699]     in call to FindClass
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:699]     from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class)
2023-07-03 20:15:55.504 20280-20280 libc                    org.home.koogel                      A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 20280 (SDLActivity), pid 20280 (SDLActivity)
2023-07-03 20:15:56.495 20430-20430 DEBUG                   pid-20430                            A  Cmdline: org.home.koogel
2023-07-03 20:15:56.495 20430-20430 DEBUG                   pid-20430                            A  pid: 20280, tid: 20280, name: SDLActivity  >>> org.home.koogel <<<
2023-07-03 20:15:56.495 20430-20430 DEBUG                   pid-20430                            A        #10 pc 000000000023c2bb  /data/app/~~N53rLpZY9mh-E3GtGYnN6Q==/org.home.koogel-igXmQKQnrfbvP2nKt24nXg==/lib/x86_64/libSDL3.so (BuildId: 92dd810fbcc704969f477fe80d5f650c31ba6464)
2023-07-03 20:15:56.495 20430-20430 DEBUG                   pid-20430                            A        #11 pc 000000000023c1f6  /data/app/~~N53rLpZY9mh-E3GtGYnN6Q==/org.home.koogel-igXmQKQnrfbvP2nKt24nXg==/lib/x86_64/libSDL3.so (JNI_OnLoad+182) (BuildId: 92dd810fbcc704969f477fe80d5f650c31ba6464)
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (20280) for package org.home.koogel ----------------------------
```

It seems like it cannot find SDL, even though I've specified the path to SDL in local properties,  and It uses an SDL library to build.
**SDLActivity:**

```
    protected String[] getLibraries() {
        return new String[] {
            "c++_shared",
            "SDL3",
            "loader",
            "image_engine",
            "image"
        };
    }
```

**local.properties:**

```
sdk.dir=/home/koogel/Android/Sdk
sdl3.dir=/home/koogel/SDL/
cmake.dir =/usr/
```

**build.gradle**

```
//adding of the SDL3 directory
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def sdl3Dir = properties.getProperty('sdl3.dir')
if (sdl3Dir == null)
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no [sdl3.dir] property in [local.properties] file")
}
```

This is actually a second time I'm reworking this project as the last time the project was built with deprecated functions and was based on the example, now I want to make my own project

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the name of the namespace, the namespace should've been org.koogel, instead of koogel.